# Graph of $|x| + |y| = 1$

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Can anybody explain as how to plot a graph of $|x| + |y| = 1$.
Here $|x|$ and $|y|$ are absolute values.

Comment: Split it into four equation by removing the modulus .

Answer (score 4):

Two solutions here (at least).

1. Notice that $|x|+|y|=1$ is the boundary of the ball of radius $1$ for the 1-norm and knowing what it does look like.
2. Or just split the cases for every quadrant ${\lbrace x \geq 0,y \geq 0 \rbrace},{\lbrace x \geq 0,y \leq0 \rbrace},\dots$

For example in ${\lbrace x \geq 0,y \geq 0 \rbrace}$, your equation is $x+y=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Following the method given by lab bhattacharjee, this is the graph you get :

[image: The Graph of |x| + |y| = 1]

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As $|y|\ge0,|x|=1-|y|\le1\implies-1\le x\le1$

Now use $$|x|=\begin{cases} x &\mbox{if } x\ge 0 \\-x  & \mbox{if } x<0\end{cases}$$